# Best phrase for teamwork ready, supportive person

Tags: word-choice

Another word- choice dilemma!

Which word or phrase is best to be used in a resume describing *ready for team work*; I am familiar whit the phrase *teamwork ready*, but it actually sounds a bit too impersonal to me. Could there be something more appropriate?

Along that line, I would want to say that I'm a *supportive* person in a work environment. But I wonder if it's to intimate to use in a resume? I want to say that I'm ready to help, to assist, to be understanding of others and the possible difficulties they might be having, while working together in a team effort.

My question is: does

> ''a cooperative worker, a supportive, responsible person'',

all together, sound ok, like it could  normally be used in a resume?

Comment: Teamwork ready implies you have not worked on teams yet. That information can be left out. However, even recent graduates must have worked on papers together with classmates, so they can describe group work. There's your teamwork.

Answer (score 12):

*Team player* comes to mind, and is very common.

*Works cooperatively* would be, perhaps, more formal.

[Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/dailymuse/2011/11/04/final-cut-words-to-strike-from-your-resume/) recommends:

> Instead of “team player,” say “Led project team of 10 to develop a new
>   system for distributing reports that reduced the time for managers to
>   receive reports by 25%.” Using a specific example, you show what you
>   can actually accomplish. But simply labeling yourself with a quality?
>   Not so much.

Comment: +1 for not only answering the question but also help the user think about writing a better resume.

Answer (score 0):

I quite like to use "***[facilitator](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/facilitate?q=facilitator#facilitate__12)***"

Someone who works to ensure things happen.

> We weren't sure the focus group would be a success but, with Susan as facilitator, the attendees made some very positive contributions.

Comment: Cool, but is it commonly used?

Comment: Yes, it's common, but only for the leader, not team members.