# What's a word for someone who switches off when things don't go their way?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a colleague who has very strong opinions on how something should be done.  When it's decided by the group to do it another way, the colleague 'switches off' from the meeting and broods on the fact that we're not doing it 'the right way' (their way) and will often refer back to that fact whenever it's brought up in later meetings.

What's a single word to describe this that will inform them without being too negative?

Comment: If you're looking for a polite way to bring this up rather than a factual description of the colleague's behaviour (e.g. *passive aggressive*), then it's off topic and you should post somewhere else, like https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can only refer to the 99% who are in step / agreement (hopefully after rechecking that the odd one out doesn't have a reasonable argument).  Eventually, Amos 3:3 needs to be accepted.

Comment: Also, Dandra, ELU requires single word requests to be accompanied by a sentence with a gap where the required word will fit. Otherwise, answers will be much too wide-ranging (eg 'focused', 'friendliness' ...).

Comment: Sulking is a form of raising a *soft fuss*. Brooding is more neutral. Stuck, frozen, and elitist are obvious. Driven and assured are the most polite.

Comment: Yes, sulking is good, so is pouting., Both are childish behaviors.

Comment: If he or she makes a HABIT of switching off when things don't go their way, you could call them contrarians. (More a suggestion than an answer.) Don

Answer (score 1):

A neutral way of describing that behavior in the workplace is to say that the person has become [disengaged](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/disengaged), i.e. [not feeling interested or involved in something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disengaged).

> After weeks of Sheila's new manager rejecting every idea she had for improving morale without explanation, she became disengaged and lost her enthusiasm for the project.

Comment: Yes, but that could be due to other reasons, such as depression.

Comment: The ask was for a word to describe the state, not what caused it?  Employee 'engagement' is a jargony workplace word these days, so in that context disengagement has a slightly different nuance. @Lambie

Answer (score 0):

For a single word describing the state the OP describes, I suggest the person is **stewing**.

**stew** (v.)

> To be in a state of suppressed agitation, worry, or resentment
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stew)

We don't know the exact nature of the person's feelings. To *stew* captures several possibilities.

---

The OP asks "**What's a single word to describe this that will inform them without being too negative?**"

You could suggest to this person that they remain a **team player/teammate** at meetings even when their suggestions aren't adopted. Using an *antonym* of sorts is more constructive becauses it focuses on what is expected, rather than simply describing their behavior with a critical word.

**team player**

> Someone who cares more about helping a group or team to succeed than
> about his or her individual success [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/team%20player)

**teammate** (if it must be a single word)

> A person who is on the same team as someone else [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/teammate)

Comment: This then becomes merely a duplicate of [best phrase for teamwork-ready supportive person](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140572/best-phrase-for-teamwork-ready-supportive-person/140576#140576).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That appears to be a different question. Others may have different ideas about this one.

Comment: Others may. That's why contributors shouldn't answer before a specimen sentence, as required for SWRs, has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be a single word, your best bet is probably **uncompromising** or one of its synonyms suggested below to describe the personality type:

[image: un·com·pro·mis·ing /ˌənˈkämprəˌmīziNG/ uncompromising showing an unwillingness to make concessions to others, especially by changing one's ways or opinions. "his uncompromising stance on the issue" harsh or relentless. "the uncompromising ugliness of the era's buildings"]

Among the synonyms suggested, **inflexible, rigid, hard-line, intractable, iron-willed, obstinate, stubborn, intransigent, headstrong** all have the not-too-negative connotation you want. (I'd include **pigheaded** but that might be too insulting to say to a work colleague).

Another good term for someone who thinks they're always right and isn't open to other ideas is **opinionated**:

[image: o·pin·ion·at·ed /əˈpinyəˌnādəd/ opinionated conceitedly assertive and dogmatic in one's opinions. "an arrogant and opinionated man"]

But if you're willing to expand your net beyond a *literal* single word, the best colloquial idiom for the *behavior pattern* of "shutting down and sulking when the group decides to do things a different way" (as opposed to the personality type of people who do this) is probably **[my way or the highway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_way_or_the_highway)**. This can also be used in something like a single-word form, *[my-way-or-the-highway](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/my-way-or-the-highway#English)*:

[image: English Adjective my-way-or-the-highway (not comparable) attributive form of my way or the highway 2004, Chuck Knowlton, "Letters," Time, 1 May, His my-way-or-the-highway attitude doesn't fit U.S. foreign-policy concerns or domestic issues.]

Comment: Opinionated is only negative, and "... stubborn, intransigent, headstrong all have the negative connotation you want." The OP asked for the opposite. Can you zero in on that alone?

Comment: @yosef I edited to clarify that those terms are “not-too-negative”. The OP is requesting a word that is negative to some extent, for purposes of constructive criticism. They obviously do not perceive their colleague’s behavior as value-neutral, much less praiseworthy.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to this behavior as "taking one's ball and going home," which is defined as follows by [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_one%27s_ball_and_go_home):

> (figuratively) To cease participating in an activity that has turned to one's disadvantage, especially out of spite, or in a way that prevents others from participating as well.
>
> [...]
>
> > 2008 May 6, Andrew Ross Sorkin, "How Not to Make a Deal," New York Times (retrieved 6 May 2015):
> >
> > [F]aced with the choice of raising his bid by a dollar or two a share or making a hostile offer, Mr. Ballmer did neither. Instead, he took his ball and went home.